# Applet throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid actions string in Java8

Tags: java, applet, java-8

Our applet throws following exception  on java8(jre 1.8._0.31) platform. Problem seems to same [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466175/illegalargumentexception-at-urlpermission-in-jre8) but one big difference this exception thrown by Plugin code block not our code block. I think Plugin is trying to load applet jar and failed. Our applet not signed but domain where it runs is in "Edit Site List". Additionally another unsigned applet at same domain works without any problem.

```
    cache: Resource http://xyz.com.tr/MyWeb/applauncher.jar has expired.
    enter basic: exception: invalid actions string.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid actions string
    at java.net.URLPermission.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLPermission.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.URLtoSocketPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheHandler.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry for wrong info. We have experienced the problem on an applet not javaws. We have no jnlp file. we have just <applet> tagged html page. And problem occurs at newly bought PC. And today problem goes. What happened I don't understand.

Comment: Since the exception is triggered by an invalid header key, the presence of that header key might depend on a certain local state which might change over time. These are the kind of bugs which are very hard to track…

Comment: Problem is come back after a reboot  caused a security fix applied to our server. Previous examination I overlooked that URL connection set cookies not set by me. Cookies include JSESSIONID. Our server WebSphere Application Server and session affinity is actived that means JSESSIONID consist of SESSIONID and CLONEID. This two value separated colon mark. It seems jsessionid causes this problem. But Interesting thing that when I asked my colleague to send log to post here she tried the start application and it worked without exception. Is it a joke?

Comment: Working log is that <code>
network: Connecting http://xyz.com.tr/MyWeb/applauncher.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://xyz.com.tr:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://xyz.com.tr/MyWeb/applauncher.jar with cookie "JSESSIONID=0000M5-4C-sPPw1_XwY6qz7JFi6:18lklp0ro; LtpaToken=blablabla"
network: Downloading resource: http://xyz.com.tr/MyWeb/applauncher.jar
                Content-Length: 297.704
                Content-Encoding: null
</code>